# How to get system time formate based on it need to list every hour for calendar event tableview using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to create custom `calendar` view with `event list`. Here, I need to get system time formate `12` or `24` based on it need to show timeLabel.text like `12.00 AM` or `24.00 AM` also current time need to show whenever user open the viewcontroller. How to achieve this?

**My CodeBelow**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 && indexPath.row != 0 && indexPath.row != 47{
            let hour = indexPath.row / 2
            cell.timeLabel.text = (hour < 10 ? "0": "") + String(hour) + ":00"
        }else{
            cell.timeLabel.text = ""
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Don't format dates using string manipulation.  Use a `DateFormatter`; this can automatically respect the user's locale and formatting preferences.

Comment: @Paulw11Could you please provide some code?